# Cool Carousel Left Menu Navigation Work with Auto Scroll with out Delay

Tags: jquery, carousel

HI I need to integrate cool carousel to my website. but i need to activate auto scroll with Left and right navigation's. But Currently when i activate auto scroll feature with out delay then left and right navigation getting disabled. Its not working. So how can i integrate left and right navigation enabled with Auto Scroll without Delay. Or Suggest me some carousel with this features. 
Now i did a code to do this actions force fully to override but in that right is working but left arrow navigation is not woking. Here i'am attaching my codes

```
var $imgWidth1 = $('#carousel1 .car-div').first().outerWidth();
var $imgCount1 = $('#carousel1 .car-div').length;
$('#carousel1').width($imgWidth1*($imgCount1+2));
$('#carousel1').css({'left':-1*$imgWidth1+'px'});//reset the slider so the first image is still visible

$('#next1').click(function(){
    $('#carousel1').stop(true,true); //complete any animation still running - in case anyone's a bit click happy... 
   var $newLeft1 = $('#carousel1').position().left-(1*$imgWidth1);//calculate the new position which is the current position minus the width of one image
   $('#carousel1').animate({'left':$newLeft1+'px'},function(){//slide to the new position...
         if (Math.abs($newLeft1) == (($imgCount1+1)*$imgWidth1)) //...and if the slider is displaying the last image, which is the clone of the first image...
         {
              $('#carousel1').css({'left':-1*$imgWidth1+'px'});//...reset the slider back to the first image without animating 
         }
     });
return false;
});

$('#prev1').click(function(){
     $('#carousel1').stop(); //complete any animation still running  
     var $newLeft1 = $('#carousel1').position().left+(1*$imgWidth1);//calculate the new position which is the current position plus the width of one image
     $('#carousel1').animate({'left':$newLeft1+'px'},function(){//slide to the new position
     if (Math.abs($newLeft1) == (($imgCount1+1)*$imgWidth1)) //if the slider is displaying the first image, which is the clone of the last image
     {
        //alert('hai');
        $('#carousel1').css({'left':-($imgCount1)*$imgWidth1+'px'});//reset the slider back to the last image without animating 
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please see the following jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kichukrishna1201/adkgkfkw/1/

Comment: Please add a demo or the html code, use jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kichukrishna1201/adkgkfkw/1/

Hi there is a delay to start this slider move.

Comment: @schnawel007 Can You Help me In this . i have added the jsfiddle